# Can I count/operate on the result of filter applied to a stream after calling distinct()/sorted() on an IntStream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm having trouble working with this stream operation.

```
Arrays.stream(array2D).forEach(ints -> {
   IntStream.of(ints)
      .filter(i -> i > 0)
      .distinct()
      .forEach(val -> { /* terminal operation */ });
});
```

[.distinct()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct--) is described in the javadoc as a [stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), so I'm assuming (although I'm still fairly new to streams) I should be able to supply some logic. This operation is supposed to be able to shift an array's non-zero elements to one side of an array, depending on the enclosing method's parameters.

Am I able to supply logic to the operation after I call distinct() on the initial filter? Not sure if this would break the no side-effect rules.

EDIT:

After a few pointers from the comments, I'm just posting what I did instead.  It's working just fine but in my initial question I was just unsure whether or not distinct() after the filter was still lazily operated or I could just skip the intermediate data structure. I'm assuming that's impossible. Here's the code:

```
    Arrays.asList(board).forEach(ints -> {

        int[] nonZero = of(ints).filter(i -> i 0 1).toArray();

        final int[] start = {(dir == LEFT) ? 0 : ints.length - nonZero.length};

        of(nonZero).forEachOrdered(val -> ints[start[0]++] = val);
        Arrays.fill(
                ints,
                (dir==LEFT) ? nonZero.length : 0,
                (dir ==LEFT) ? ints.length : ints.length - nonZero.length,
                0);
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can modify the underlying array in the inner stream's terminal operation?  The answer to that would be no, because the no side-effect rules are specifically about modifying the source of the stream data as you are streaming.

Comment: If you find yourself creating a stream from a collection or array only to immediately call the terminal operation `forEach`, it's more efficient to not use streams, and instead use `Collection`'s `forEach`. In your case that would be `Arrays.asList(array2D).forEach(...)`.

Comment: @HankD Maybe I should have left out the 2D array - any effect would only be confined to that specific array, so I don't understand what you're trying to say in your last comment.  It's not the terminal operation for the entire thing, rather the single array

Comment: My second comment doesn't have any bearing on your question. I'm just saying that `Arrays.asList(array2D).forEach(...)` is probably going to perform better than `Arrays.stream(array2D).forEach(...)`

Comment: @HankD makes sense, thanks

Comment: When you say "Am I able to supply logic to the operation" does "the operation" refer to the `/* terminal operation */`?  If so, then the answer would be that, yes, the terminal operation can have logic in it after `distinct()` as long as it doesn't modify the `ints` array that underlies the stream

Comment: Whatever you are trying to interpret into `distinct()` (it’s not really clear), the answer is most probably *no*. Besides that, `final int[] start = {(dir == LEFT) ? 0 : ints.length - nonZero.length}; of(nonZero).forEachOrdered(val -> ints[start[0]++] = val);` is an awful abuse of the API, whereas a simple `System.arraycopy(nonZero, 0, ints, dir==LEFT? 0 : ints.length-nonZero.length, nonZero.length)` does that cleaner *and* simpler…

Comment: @Holger I didn't ask how to use the API.  I asked if such a thing was possible.  Arraycopy is to overwrite the old values at the end of streaming over the array and pulling the ones I need, the two are not compatible. How am I abusing the API? I 1) pulled elements from an array and stored them in an intermediate array. 2) I perform some logic on the values. 3) I change the values of the original array.  No elements are operating on themselves.  Is it simply because of the 1 element array hack?

Comment: “I asked if such a thing was possible” Sorry, it’s still not clear *what* you are asking. You seem to interpret something odd into the `distinct()` operation, which isn’t even related to your described task, as you are not intending to process *distinct* values at all. I would be happy to answer your question, but it’s not possible. Yes, the code is an abuse of the API, *not only* due to the array hack, as it modifies external data *with interference*. Using `forEachOrdered` this way should be the last resort, but there is a simple and clean alternative, like `arraycopy`…

Comment: @Holger humor me, shift the values of an int array to one side using a simpler solution and also without using a traditional for loop.  I also just initially misunderstood what distinct does